# Right-padding, or, zero-padding a left-justified string

Tags: ruby, string, format

I have a numeric value, and I want create a string by converting it to binary and then left justifying, appending zeroes (rather than spaces) to the right side. Is it possible to do this with a single/simple string format sequence?

Attempts include:

```
"%032b" % 94426294 #=> "00000101101000001101010010110110"
"%-032b" % 94426294 #=>"101101000001101010010110110     "
"%0-32b" % 94426294 #=>"101101000001101010010110110     "
"%-032b0" % 94426294 #=>"101101000001101010010110110     0"
"%-b032" % 94426294 #=>"101101000001101010010110110032"
"%-032.30b" % 94426294 #=>"000101101000001101010010110110  "
format("%-32b",94426294) #=>"101101000001101010010110110     "
format("%-32.32b",94426294) #=>"00000101101000001101010010110110"
```

I can get what I want by something like

```
("%b" % 94426294).ljust(32,'0') #=>"10110100000110101001011011000000"
```

but is this the best method available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you want to append to the right side? This would change the value:

```
"10110100000110101001011011000000".to_i(2)
 => 3021641408
```

I think that your solution is the shortest.
This sounds reasonable for me that you cannot **format** some value **changing** its value **at the same time**.

That is why `%` allows 'appending' only to the left side. (because its purpose is to format and not to change the value)

Comment: Aye; I was intending to parse it in groups of bits from the left/most significant, in a process that I don't expect to go more than a few steps down, it's not as important that it have a particular value as that I end up with a variety of distinguishable values, rather than say, 10000 values where the first 5-7 bits are all '000...' 

That said your reasoning for why it wouldn't allow that makes some sense.